# Some fundamental theory of calc 2 questions.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate these integrals. I think I understand it, but I just wanted to check:

1. $$\int_{-1}^1 x^{100} dx$$
   $$\frac{1^{101}}{101} - \frac{-1^{101}}{101}$$
   $$= \frac{1}{101} + \frac{1}{101} = \frac{2}{101}$$
2. $$\int_{1}^9 \sqrt{x} dx$$
   $$\frac{2}{3} \cdot 9^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{2}{3}$$
   $$ = 18 - \frac{2}{3}$$
   $$17 \frac{1}{3}$$
3. $$\int_{1}^8 x^{\frac{-2}{3}} dx$$
   So an antiderivative we can use is: $F(x) = \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{3}$
   $$ \frac{8^{\frac{1}{3}}}{3} - \frac{1^{\frac{1}{3}}}{3}$$
   $$ = \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$
4. $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^\pi \sin \theta dx$$
   $$ - \cos \pi - -\cos \frac{\pi}{6} $$
   $$ = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
   $$= \frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: This is four questions; please limit your posts  to one specific articulable item. Also, if all you want is verification, you might as well just use a calculator....

Comment: WolframAlpha is a very powerful, free, online calculator for just this kind of purpose.

Comment: I'd double check your anti-derivative in part 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @littleO points out, the antiderivative of part 3 is incorrect.

$$\int_{1}^8 x^{-2/3} dx = \left[ \frac{x^{1/3}}{1/3} \right]_1^8 = [3\sqrt[3]{x}]_1^8 = 3(2-1) = 3$$

The rest is correct.